# Why didn't the Formics recognize us as sentient beings?

Tags: enders-game

Why didn't the Buggers/Formics recognize us as sentient beings? I know that they recognize sentience as having a "Hive Mind" and as we didn't communicate with them in their way(mind to mind) they thought us as animals.

But of course, we already had spaceships, that means intelligence. How come they never recognized that intelligence in us? And if they did and they did recognize intelligence but only counted the killing of the human "Hive Mind" as real murder and the rest of the humans as dispensable, they are still invading us and what would they do when all the "dispensable" people were killed, what would they do with our supposed Hive Mind? Besides, with the millions of people they killed and all the shows of courage, independent and intelligent thought and probably sacrifice (I'm thinking mother to save their child, etc.) shown in the Earth books how come they never once questioned our sentience?

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]. Please limit each question to only one topic. If you have multiple topics you want to ask about, please create multiple questions.

Comment: Also, please note that this isn't a site for discussion or debate, but for verifiable correct answers. You shouldn't be hoping for debate, but for single correct answers to your questions. Most of these questions if asked separately will get put on hold as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll divide the questions into topics.

Thanks Mike, I really do hope for single correct answers but I doubt there are a single correct answers

Comment: Sismetic, I think the real question is "if the Formics thought we were like them, what did they intend to do with our hive mind?"

Comment: Courage, independent thought, sacrifice... were probably utterly alien to the formics. *You* think of them as a clear sign of intelligence (though note that you'd acknowledge dogs as human-like intelligences too :P), because that's what you see all around yourself, and everywhere in media. The same simply wasn't true with the Hive Queens. The first sacrifice they made that we know of was the mass suicide on their homeworld - before that, you sacrificed your workers, not yourself. Hordes of humans desperately trying to fight and dying must have made them *more* sure that we're just "drones".

Answer (score 18):

They did recognize our sentience, they simply did not recognize where it resides. In the formic society only the queens are sentient, and the worker formics are mindless drones, and therefore expendable. So, when the formics encountered humans, they initially assumed that individual humans were also expendable mindless drones. They could just as well have interpreted the courage and sacrifice of humans as actions of drones directed by a "queen".

Comment: Fair enough answer, that's what I thought too... But then what was the plan of the Formics? After killing all our "drones"? What would they do with our "queen"? That is still invading the hometown of another sentient species and declaring war

Comment: I don't know, giving someone a hard shove or knocking them down is aggresive, but not really declaring war.  I think in their eyes they were more testing the diplomatic waters than starting a war. They didn't think they were killing anyone, so they didn't think they were escalating things nearly as much as we perceived.

Comment: I like this because it brings to light the following question: If the first queen had to look so hard to find a capable peer, why was finding a peer not on the menu in their posture toward other species?

Comment: @EngrStudent They tried - they just couldn't "reach" us. They had known of no other way of communication than the philotes, and those didn't work with humans. They didn't try very hard at first, but after the failure of their first colonisation attempt, they have tried for *decades* to communicate with humans (it was even implied this was a big part of the reason why Ender's predecessors failed - utterly broken by the communication attempts). Ender was the first human they managed to properly communicate with, a little bit too late - and even that was described as exhausting for the Queens.

Answer (score 0):

In the First Formic Wars series, it is mentioned that Formic drones were apparently "searching" for something in the corpses of humans whose ships were brought into the scout ship by tearing open their bodies. It can be assumed that the object of their search was whatever organ in the hive queen allows it to command its drones. Essentially, they were trying to find the human hive queen, but never succeeded, because one did not exist.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence of such, how does this relate to the Formics not recognising humans as sentient?

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding a quote from the book.